# Windows 8 VHD on Mac

Tags: mac, vhd, windows-8, boot-camp

I am trying to create a VHD of windows 8 on my macbook pro.  I started by following [this Hansellman aticle](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx).

However, I found the following FAQ on [another Hansellman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx):

> Can I do this on a Mac?
>
> No. Apple MacOS uses Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI)
>   which locks the Guid Partition Table (GPT). The GPT holds a similar
>   position in the UEFI systems as MBR for the BIOS systems.

However, in the comments, I found a user who got it working:

> Finished installation on Mac (had to install to VHD since bootcamp
>   doesn't support two Windows installations). Aside from a problem with
>   bootcamp setup not wanting to start everything went fine. Running
>   bcdboot.exe W:\Windows under Windows 7 32bit somehow successfully
>   managed to update the main bootloader from the VHD Windows 8 64bit
>   install. Cool. I thought it would only add 8 to the 7's OS list.

However, his comment doesn't really make sense to me.  I am a software developer and my sys admin skills are definitely lacking.  Can anyone explain how I can get this to work?

On a side note, when I try to do it myself, I get the following warning when trying to select the VHD as the disk to install windows 8 to:

> Windows cannot be install to this disk.  The selected disk has an MBR
>   partition table.  On EFI Systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT
>   disks.

And it doesn't let me select it for installation.

Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Zack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with your environment, but below is some info that might be useful.

The article below shows how to install Windows 8 for dual-boot in a partition :
[How To Try Out Windows 8 On Your MacBook Air](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-8-macbook-air/).
I believe that the procedure that is described, creating a bootable USB stick with Boot Camp Assistant, can solve the problem you have with the boot CD.

In any case, I think that you need to create the Windows 8 VHD using the Windows environment, unless you have an existing VHD that you can already boot.
Otherwise, If you have a Windows computer or a Windows virtual machine you should use it to create the VHD,

Below is a very detailed article on the procedure once the VHD exists.
However, the guy already had a Boot Camp installation of Windows 7 on his computer.
[Sells Manor: Running 64-bit Win8 on My MacBook Air](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/12708)

Comment: The real issue here is creating the VHD with a mac.  This doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried using a bootable USB stick ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is obviously not what I was hoping to hear.  However, if it can't be done then that's not your fault.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the comment you referred to is a user who installed a VHD inside of an existing bootcamp partition. You can't do a VHD inside of Mac OS X because of the UEFI. The best solution to this is to install it directly on a partition, following any of the numerous "install windows 7 bootcamp" guides out there, or alternatively, to install another version of windows (7, ideally), and install Windows 8 on a VHD inside of the Windows 7 partition.

(Sidenote: I'm currently running Windows 8 on a Macbook pro directly through Bootcamp.)

Comment: This is exactly what I have told the poster in my answer, but he does not seem willing to accept.

Comment: @harrymc You're right - I just read your answer again and you *did* cover what I thought was missing.

Comment: Having added your voice and experience might make the poster listen after all.

Comment: @xdumaine Please explain what "You can't do a VHD inside of Mac OS X" means.

Comment: @Matt Read the question for the context. Can't create a VHD inside of Mac OS X.

Comment: @xdumaine Honestly I am not meaning to be a wise guy but the question isn't that clear either.  I guess the statement "I am trying to create a VHD of windows 8 on my macbook pro." means "I am trying to boot my Mac from a Windows VHD."?

Comment: @Matt The user was trying to create  VHD for windows to be booted virtually (something like Parallels) directly inside of a host operating system. That host operating system cannot be Mac OS X because of the UEFI problem. The host operating system MUST be windows, but you can do it on Mac hardware, if you're booting directly into an existing windows installation (like bootcamp, not virtual like parallels), then creating the VHD inside of the existing windows installation.

Comment: @xdumaine - Ah ok - so the user was trying to use bootcamp to boot to vhd which is not possible, but you are saying you can run a regular windows bootcamp installation and boot from vhd in that, correct?

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @xdumaine Since this scenario requires a much higher disk space requirement given that you've added a regular Windows installation (if it were not for the uefi problem you could boot from vhd via bootcamp and avoid the extra Windows install), can I do the following: After my setup is complete and I've got Windows booting via bootcamp and then I create a VHD and boot from that, can I delete all the Windows files and continue to boot from the VHD just using the Windows boot menu that will exist as a result of the bootcamp config?

Comment: @Matt Join me in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13443/windows-installation-on-apple-hardware